Incredibly slow count(*) on MariaDB / MySQL
Running EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activities shows it plans to use the secondary index with and only one column int and keylen of 5. Action takes anywhere from 2 minutes to 6 minutes, sporadically
Background

MariaDB - version 10.11.7
Partitioned InnoDB table by date-range
600M records in the table
Table size
Regular operations take reasonable time i.e. up to 2-3 minutes
3 indices defined, none on text, all BTREE -

Primary - int(11) + datetime, index size is ~30% of the table size
Index-1, nullable, non unique - index int(11), size is ~15% of the table size
Index-1, nullable, non unique - index int(11), size is ~15% of the table size


Partition is monthly i.e. PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(activity_datetime)
Isolation level was set REPEATABLE-READ (it was changed after the problem occurred hence this isn't the cause, but neither the solution)
Standalone server with 64GB RAM, solely serves the DB
innodb_buffer_pool_size set to 50GB
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size set to 1GB
innodb_read_io_threads set to 8 (changed from default 4)
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS - shows nothing special, deadlock rarely happens, and for sure isn't the cause

Attempted changes:

Set the Isolation level to REPEATABLE-READ
count(id) instead of count(*)
Adjusted system variables, mainly -

Increased innodb_buffer_pool_size to 50GB
Increased innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size to 2GB
Increased innodb_read_io_threads to 8


Tested the same on a table copy with indices
Tested the same on a table copy with no partition usage

Afraid nothing helped, count(*) is super slow, and 99.99% is spent on 'sending data'
1   Starting           28 µs
2   Checking Permissions   6 µs
3   Opening Tables         23 µs
4   After Opening Tables.  15 µs
5   System Lock            18 µs
6   Table Lock             4 µs
7   Init                   7 µs
8   Optimizing             4 µs
9   Statistics             19 µs
10  Preparing              26 µs
11  Executing              2 µs
**12    Sending Data           358.4 s**
13  End Of Update Loop.    20 µs
14  Query End              3 µs
15  Commit                 6 µs
16  Closing Tables         4 µs
17  Unlocking Tables       2 µs
18  Closing Tables         15 µs
19  Starting Cleanup       3 µs
20  Freeing Items          6 µs
21  Updating Status        14 µs
22  Reset For Next Command 4 µs

Create Table
CREATE TABLE `contact_activity` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_list` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activity` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_contact` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_isp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_esp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_esp_connection` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_message` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_campaign` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activity_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `os` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_platform` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`activity_datetime`),
  KEY `id_contact` (`id_contact`),
  KEY `id_list` (`id_list`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=629997644 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci
 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(`activity_datetime`)
(PARTITION `pMonth_231` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-01-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_232` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-02-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_233` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-03-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_234` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-04-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_235` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-05-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_236` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-06-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_237` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-07-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_238` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-08-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_239` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-09-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_2310` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-10-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_2311` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-11-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_2312` VALUES LESS THAN ('2023-12-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_241` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-01-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_242` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-02-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_243` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-03-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_244` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-04-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_245` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-05-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_246` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-06-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_247` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-07-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_248` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-08-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_249` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-09-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_2410` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-10-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_2411` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-11-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMonth_2412` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-12-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pMaxMonth` VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = InnoDB) 


Instead of describing the DDL/DML, please actually include it verbatim. Plus explain plans, etc. Actual output.

What is the write activity like on this server?

@MatBailie there's no write activity as this is reproduced in our staging env as well, the server is rather idle. EXPLAIN is straight-forward - there you go -
id = 1
select_type = SIMPLE
table = zzz_contact_activity_test
type = Index
possible_keys = NULL
key = id_contact
key_len = 5
ref = NULL
rows = 614,622,853
Extra = Using index

@MichaelModan Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE activities; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name like "activities";  and C) TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT ..... for us.  The EXPLAIN clearly says possible_keys = NULL so we can not be sure how then the key = id_contact with a key_len of 5.

Additional DB information request, please.
OS, Version?
cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after COMPLETING the SLOW COUNT.
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  taken 1 MINUTE BEFORE SLOW COUNT COMPLETION, please.
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to try to detect SLOW contributors.

Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE,
top -b -n 1  for most active apps,
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage,
ulimit -a       for list of limits,
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count,
df -h  for Used - Free space by device,
df -i  for inode info by device,
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:,
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Please also post last 100 lines of your Slow Query Log.

Could there be any keyboards connected to this server, logged in with a cup of coffee sitting on the keyboard - generating interruptions?

You may find netstat -s helpful (statistics by protocol) and then 2 minutes later to see which protocol's are BUSY.

@WilsonHauck - I don't have the exact specs of the machine, it is however with 64GB of RAM, SSD and 8 or 16 cores. It's a stand-alone very powerful dedicated server. I'll post on a separate comments the CREATE TABLE statement, along with InnoDB status. I'll also search for the slow query log. Thanks.

Michael,  SELECT @@slow_query_log_file;  will reveal the filename and maybe the path to it.  If you could post OS information requested, we will know how many cores you have.

When you run out of space here, Please post TEXT results to justpaste.it rather than thinking you are at a dead end.

@WilsonHauck afraid I can't paste the InnoDB log here, and the slow_query was disabled, I'll enable now and hope to have more info later.
I'll look into netstat -s.
I also plan to attempt and drop some columns, I must find the answer to this annoying enigma...

Please view my profile for contact info.

key = id_contact key_len = 5 -- This is to be expected.  It means that is is doing a full index scan on KEY(id_contact), which is the best it can do for getting COUNT(*).
Requesting COUNT(id) would check each id for not-null and be slightly faster.
